# How to use NSTask with pbcopy?

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, foundation, pbcopy

I am a beginner and I have a problem. I would like to use NSTask with the command "pbcopy". I tried this but it seems that it doesn't work :

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/echo"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"my-text-to-copy", @"| pbcopy", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

[task launch];
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

---

It works fine :

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];

task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/echo"];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe]; // write to pipe
[task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"tmp", nil]];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/pbcopy"];
[task setStandardInput:pipe]; // read from pipe
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe ("|") is a feature of the shell, not an argument to the command you're using. You have to use two `NSTasks`, one for echo and one for pbcopy and set up an `NSPipe` between them.

Btw, I'm assuming that you're just using this as an example. Otherwise it would be much simpler to use `NSPasteboard` for this.

Comment: pbcopy is located in /usr/bin, not /bin.